# Is there another way to write line 6

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery and I am not familiar with the way of writing code in line 6. I just want a simple way to write and understand it (it is supposed to select the id "data-scroll" that equals blockID)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".block").each(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(this).offset().top){
            var blockID = $(this).attr("id");
            $("nav a").removeClass("active");
            $('nav a[data-scroll="' + blockID + '"]').addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That is an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) and it's not jQuery-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) but as @msg noted that's not jQuery specific.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".block").each(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(this).offset().top){
            var blockID = $(this).attr("id");
            $("nav a").removeClass("active");
            $(`nav a[data-scroll="${blockID }"]`).addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Need a bit more context, but you can use template literals as @harry suggested or simply modifying your simple example.

You don't need the double qoutes in your snippet.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".block").each(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(this).offset().top){
            var blockID = $(this).attr("id");
            $("nav a").removeClass("active");
            $('nav a[data-scroll=' + blockID + ']').addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), it's not jQuery specific and it allows to match elements having a specific value for an attribute. Your best bet is learning how it works, but here are a couple of alternatives using [`.filter`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) and the [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property and its jQuery equivalent, [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) (although it's not simpler):

Javascript:

```
// Get all links in nav
$('nav a')
    // Reduce the collection to those having data-scroll == blockID
    .filter(function() { return this.dataset.scroll == blockID })
    // Add the class
    .addClass("active");
```

jQuery syntax:

```
$('nav a').filter(function() { return $(this).data('scroll') == blockID }).addClass("active");
```